# Browserify duplicates library code

Tags: browserify, browserify-shim

I want to place all vendors libraries (like jQuery, moment.js, bootstrap.js and so on) code into *vendors.js* file and export jQuery from it to reuse it in other modules.

because of bootstrap is dependent from jQuery, I shimed both modules and configure dependencies:

**package.json**

```
"browser": {
    "bootstrap": "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js",
    "jquery": "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"
  },
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [
      "browserify-shim"
    ]
  },
  "browserify-shim": "gulp/utilities/shim-config.js"
```

**shim-config.js**

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
  'jquery'    :  'jQuery',
  'bootstrap' :  { 'depends': { 'jquery': 'jQuery'} }
};
```

to reuse *jQuery* as external dependency I specified it in `require` method call, when build my *vendors.js*

```
build
 .require('jQuery')
 .bundle()
 .pipe(source('vendors.js'))
 .pipe(gulp.dest('build/public/js'))
 .pipe(plumber({
  errorHandler: helpers.logError
}));
```

after building *vendors.js* I found, that *jQuery* code was included into *vendors.js* twice: one time to resolve dependency and one more time to export library. Considering size of *jQuery* it is significant issue.

Can anyone pls help me to solve it?

Comment: try here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667340/gulp-browserify-maps