# Gulp Browserify SourceMaps

Tags: gulp, browserify, source-maps

I've looked at this question already and the answer doesn't work in my situation: [gulp, browserify, maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667340/gulp-browserify-maps)

So here is what I have:

```
gulp.task('debug-app-js', function () {
    console.log('DEBUG-APP-JS');
    var src = './node_modules/js/app-main.js',
        dst = '../www/js',
        bundler = browserify(src, {debug:true});

    return bundler.bundle()
        .pipe(source('app-build.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(dst))
});
```

Debug is set to true, so why don't I get any sourcemaps?

UPDATE: It appears to be an IE problem as the sourcemaps are appearing in Chrome and Firefox. But it's strange because I ***was*** getting sourcemaps in IE with my previous browserify build process. But now I can't seem to get any sourcemaps in IE no matter what browserify process I use. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried the gulp recipe? https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/browserify-uglify-sourcemap.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the solution was I was trying to use browserify-shim transforms, which apparently wrecks the source maps for IE.