# Gulp+Browserify+Babel+Sourcemaps: Source map contains duplicate code

Tags: node.js, gulp, browserify, source-maps, gulp-sourcemaps

I've got the following for my gulpfile:

```
const gulp = require("gulp");
const sourcemaps = require("gulp-sourcemaps");
const browserify = require("browserify");
const source = require("vinyl-source-stream");
const buffer = require("vinyl-buffer");
const babel = require("babel");
const uglify = require("uglify");

gulp.task("default", function() {
    return browserify("src/app.js", {debug: true})
        .bundle()
        .pipe(source("app.js"))
        .pipe(buffer())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}))
        .pipe(babel({presets: ["env"]}))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write("/src"))
        .pipe(glup.dest("dist"));
});
```

Pretty standard stuff. My `src/app.js` contains only the following:

```
const $ = require("jquery");
console.log($);
```

Now when I run `gulp` and look in the Chrome console, I see the following:

[image]

The first `app.js` file in this list, located in `src/js/app.js`, is my actual source file, containing two lines of code.

The last `app.js` file in this list, located in `app.js` (no subdirectory), is the compiled and minified version with one line of incomprehensible garbage

The middle one, however, located in `src/app.js`, contains the full browserified source before running babel or uglify (the "const" keyword is still present and it's multi-line and entirely readable)

This makes my source map twice as large as it needs to be, as it contains the entire source code of the project ***twice***. Any tips on cleaning it up?

### Update

Doing a few quick tests, I've narrowed the issue down to Babel.

When I remove Babel and just run Uglify (modifying `app.js` to remove the `const` keywords so Uglify doesn't barf on me) I don't get the duplicate code in my source map.

When I remove Uglify and just run Babel, I still get the duplicate code.

For some reason when Babel sees the output from Browserify it seems to treat both the original source maps ***and*** the original source ***file*** as source code (putting them both in the final source map).

Is there something I need to pass to Babel to fix this?

Comment: here an older solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667340/gulp-browserify-maps it worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I didn't find a way to get it working with Babel directly, I did find a way to bypass the `.pipe(babel())` step:

```
npm install --save-dev babelify
```

If you use the Browserify transform instead of using Babel directly, then the source maps are never wrong in the first place:

```
// Most of the file omitted for brevity. Only new / different stuff shown
const babelify = require("babelify");

browserify("app.js", {debug: true})
    .transform(babelify, {presets: ["env"]})
    .bundle()
```

This works as expected and created a source map with only one instance of all code.